# Is there a way to check index limits of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have a simple vector of 20 elements in which all values are NA.

```
a = rep(NA, 20)
```

At some specific intervals, I have assigned a few NA values to 2

```
a[c(1, 8, 15, 20)] = 2
```

Now, I want to assign all values after values 2 to 3. The following statement works fine, but it adds a new element to the vector at index 21. However, I do not want to increase the size of the vector.

```
a[which(a == 2) + 1] <- 3
```

Is there a way to check the limits of this vector and assign value 3 only within vector boundaries?

Comment: `pmin` is another option to get the indices right: `pmin(which(a==2)+1, length(a))`

Comment: Also conisder to accept/upvote existing answers if they helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to not do the `nth` value of the vector in the comparison. Instead, we will only compare to `n-1`.

```r
a[which(head(a, -1L)  == 2) + 1] <- 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the simplest one I can figure out.

```
library(zoo)
a = rep(NA, 20)
a[c(1, 8, 15, 20)] = 2
a[which(a == 2 & index(a) < length(a)) + 1] <- 3
```

Comment: What is ```index()``` from? I tried the code but it does not seem to be a part of base.

Comment: It is part of ```zoo``` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those index which are greater than the length of `a`.

```
a <- rep(NA, 20)
ind <- c(1, 8, 15, 20)
a[ind] = 2
new_ind <- ind + 1
new_ind <- new_ind[new_ind > 0 & new_ind < length(a)]
a[new_ind] <- 3
a
#[1]  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA  2  3 NA NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to initially store the `length` of your vector and then select the values as per your initial dimension.

```
a = rep(NA, 20)
dim_a <- length(a) 
a[c(1, 8, 15, 20)] = 2
a[which(a == 2) + 1] <- 3

a[seq_len(dim_a)] #select all elements up until length of initial a

#2  3 NA NA NA NA NA  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA  2  3 NA NA NA  2
```